# CM API - Clearcase Resource Proxy Unable to Resolve

Tags: java, clearcase

Clearcase Resource proxy, CcFile instance, holding a file in working snapshot view, is throwing exception while invoked resolve() method. Whereas, it keep waiting forever, when invoked doResolve() method which contacts the clearcase server.

Code used for retrieving the proxy class:

```
StpProvider provider = (StpProvider) ProviderFactory.createProvider(CcProvider.NETWORK_PROVIDER_CLASS, callback);

provider.setServerUrl(serverUrl);

provider = provider.ccProvider();

StpLocation loc = provider.filePathLocation(Domain.CLEAR_CASE, new File("windowsDrive:/folders/fileName.sql"));

CcFile proxy = provider.ccFile(loc);

proxy.doResolve(); //This method supposed to invoke CC server and update proxy information, but it's keep waiting forever.

(or)

proxy.resolve();
```

Throws below exception:

> Exception in thread "main" CcException: CRMAP7013: File is not in a
>   ClearCase view: cc.file:windowsDrive:/folders/fileName.sql
>
> reason:   client-location-not-in-file-area
>
> resource: null at
>   com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileAreaFactory.locationToClientState(CcFileAreaFactory.java:114)
>
> at
>   com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.getClientState(CcFileImpl.java:174)
>
> at
>   com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.readProperties(CcFileImpl.java:660)
>
> at
>   com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.resolve(CcFileImpl.java:652)

Any help on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause being that Clearcase client does not support snapshot views in my client/server version 8.0.0.10. This feature is only added after 8.1. So, i switched to dynamic view and this problem is now resolved.